# Is there a difference between the words "concious" and "conscious" (and is the former even a word)?

Tags: spelling

My auto-spelling software seems to accept `concious` as a word. Is it correct to do so (for historic or whatever reasons), and is there in any case a difference between `concious` and `conscious`?

Comment: I checked six online dictionaries and could not find "concious". Perhaps this spelling ended up in your spellchecker because you accidentally accepted it while writing an other text?

Comment: @ChristipheStrobbe That's a highly plausible cause, but I almost never correct the spell-checker, and in addition just started using a new writing tool (LaTeX; although it just might be wrong #opensource). Internet seems to use the word (518000 hits on Google), hence i thought it better to ask.

Comment: I saw that @Chris stated that you may have inadvertantly saved the incorrect spelling of the word conscious in your dictionary that controls the spell checker and free dictionary lookup on your device that is accepting the misspelling of the word as 'concious' when typed. I too have had this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concious), `concious` is just a common misspelling of `conscious`.

Comment: Noted. Who wrote Wiktionary, though?

Comment: @DJHellduck Like any Wiki, it is entirely sourced by the community. Some information about how that works is written on its [Main Page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page).

Comment: So it is. But if you look at the post history, you could count the number of people involved with that entry on one hand, most of which seem to be bots. Essentially you are asking me to take one anonymous user's word for it.

Comment: You're not taking just one user's word for it, but an entire community of editors who are constantly improving and keeping up with the pages on Wiktionary.

If that's not enough, I found another source: http://www.esl-lounge.com/reference/vocabulary-reference-common-misspellings.php

Comment: I know I'm being difficult now, but my faith in wiki-knowledge is not very high (and neither should yours btw - ref alternative facts, post-truth etc). Thanks for searching around for that second source, although most random things on the internet is at best questional imo (perhaps best explained by [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/978/)). Will you edit it into your answer, or shall I?